# How to navigate to nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, nested

I've a problem trying to navigate to a property from an nested object using nodejs and mongodb.

Here is my function:

```
async function obtenerInscripciones(username) {

    const inscripcionesDB = await Inscripcion.find({ username: username._id }).populate({
        path: 'clase',
        select: '_id',
    })
    console.log(inscripcionesDB, WORKING); // **working**
    console.log(inscripcionesDB.clase._id, NOT WORKING); // **undefined**
    return inscripcionesDB;
}
```

My output is like this

```
{
    estado: 'CANCELADA',
    _id: 5d959abc0d3ee404889d2b28,
    clase: { _id: 5d82e5525770f32b5024665a },
    username: 5d917b2cb531bc2a94a3d476,
  },  **WORKING**

(node:18380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined, NOT **WORKING**
```

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The word "async" before a function means one simple thing: the function always returns a promise.

```
async function obtenerInscripciones(username) {
    return await Inscripcion.find({
        username: username._id
    }).populate({
        path: 'clase',
        select: '_id',
    })
}

obtenerInscripciones(username).then((response) => {
    console.log('response', response)
})
```